# I cant register a new mysql server on netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans, connection

I have installed MySQL 5.6.26.0 and I tried to connect to a database. I found out that I still need to register a new MySQL server. But the Register option is not available and I do not know why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Go through this link  http://netbeans6.blogspot.in/2008/03/registering-database-in-netbeans-ide.html..This may help

Comment: Tried it just now but I still cant register a new mysql server. Thanks though

Comment: Download wamp server.try it